# How to Add the Firefox and Chrome to C# Browser Control?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Can you please let me know how I can add other browser controls like Chrome, Firefox, ... to C# web browser control?I am trying to create a HTML and CSS rules tester in C# and I need to have all of them inside the application

Comment: The WebBrowser control is built on IE. You can't use it for other browsers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you merely want to use other browsers, not add Chrome or Firefox to the C# Web Browser control...here are some helpful links:

CefSharp Embedded Chromium for .NET: https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp

Embedding Gecko (firefox engine): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Gecko/Embedding_Mozilla/FAQ/Embedding_Gecko

Comment: Thanks David, These are exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Behseini FYI, the link to GeckoFX on that page is broken. You can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

Comment: Interesting that such things exist. I can see why one might want such a thing for test automation. Can anyone think of any *other* need? I mean genuine need, not merely pandering to pathological dislike of IE.

Comment: A lot of apps like to include browser capability within the app. If you wanted to do that and support HTML5 to a higher level than IE supports it, then the Chromium deal could work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The web browser control hosts the MSHTML COM object only.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 2016:**

If you need to have all browsers inside your application I suggest you take a look at the below component.

[BrowseEmAll Core API](http://www.browseemall.com/CoreAPI)

Need all the different browsers in your .Net Application? Which the BrowseEmAll Core API you can **integrate Chrome, Firefox, Webkit and Internet Explorer** into your application. This is a **commercial product** though so be warned.

*(Full disclosure: I work for this company so take everything I say with a grain of salt)*