# Mozilla based web browser control for VB6

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, activex, mozilla, gecko

In my VB6 application I am using web-browser control(Microsoft internet control). I want to use Mozilla based web browser control instead of Microsoft internet control. I found several links about [gecko control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713596/how-to-add-the-firefox-and-chrome-to-c-sharp-browser-control).It also had many references in Mozilla website and developed by Mozilla. But is it only available for .net , not for vb6? Then I found [Mozilla ActiveX Control](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm). It seems to work, but I want to know is it same as gecko and can be used in my application? Is there any disadvantage in using it?

Comment: Since VB6 was released more than 15 years ago, your options are likely to be limited.

Comment: @Plutonix ok. Do you mean gecko cannot be used? I have just used Mozilla ActiveX Control and able to do basic working of web browser control. Don't know about gecko

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you could hope for is that Mozilla has an API you can access from VB6.

That'll be a lot harder to use if you want to embed a browser in your app.